# What is a subspace and what is a shared subspace?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, multilabel-classification

I'm totally new in machine learning. The first confusing concept is subspace. In multi label classification we have to share the subspace. What does one mean by that shared sub spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "In multi label classification we have to share the subspace.", but the concept of subspaces is fairly easy to explain.

> In mathematics, a space is a set (sometimes called a universe) with some added structure.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics))

The most common spaces are $\mathbb{R}$ (the number line), $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the plane) and $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the space we often think in, with $x,y,z$ axes). Lets assume our main space is $\mathbb{R}^3$. Our data are datapoints in this space. However, we have to write a report. This report has to be printed on paper. Hence we project the data points from a 3-dimensional space to a two-dimensional subspace. So a subspace is just a part of the original space.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first explain an easier concept, which is the subset? 
Subset is related " in general" to ensemble classifiers. In ensemble classifier, you combine the outputs of multiple outputs of different base learners " weak learners". One of the important keys is having diversity. That different base learners have different abilities. One of the easiest way to achieve diversity is by using subset learning. Each time you train a base learner you sample from the training data, since this sampling process is randomly, these base learner will not be the same and thus you support diversity. 
What about subspace?
In subspace, you use all samples, but each time you select different set of dimensions. 
For example, let us say that each sample is a vector 1*100 
The first base learner can be trained by using all samples but only the first 10 dimensions. So the first base learner will be trained by using samples where each is 1*10.
By choosing random number of dimensions and random dimensions you support diversity

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

You are doing multi-label classification, so each of your examples might be associated with multiple labels.

In the image, any example in the labelled 'shared subspace' could be labelled as A and B

[image: Shared subspace]